# How to turn off "error" highlighting in emacs-lisp-mode for Emacs 25?

Tags: elisp, font-lock, emacs-lisp-mode

Since the update, a certain style of formatting code is highlighted with `font-lock-warning-face`:

How do I turn off this behavior?

[image]

Comment: Could it be the theme? I was tweaking [`zop-to-char`](https://github.com/thierryvolpiatto/zop-to-char) yesterday and I don't see that `nil` highlighted in `font-lock-warning-face`: [My screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/nI7ZwX7.png?1). I am also on 24.4. The difference I guess is that I am using `zenburn` theme. And it does highlight `font-lock-warning-face` at places I expect.

Comment: It's reproducible with `emacs -Q`.

Comment: I can confirm this does happen. I find it useful because it highlights that the return value is not what it seems.

Comment: Strange.. why am I not seeing that even on `emacs -Q`? [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/YcACYO0.png). Again, I am also using emacs 24.4.

Comment: @Malabarba, it highlights red because `nil` isn't on a new line. It's just a text formatting issue.

Comment: @Malabarba, does that highlighting happen for you for [this exact code snippet](https://github.com/thierryvolpiatto/zop-to-char/blob/master/zop-to-char.el#L56-60)?

Comment: @abo-abo The fact that nil isn't on a newline gives the wrong impression this entire expression returns the return value of `kill-region`. Highlighting the `nil` makes it clear that the expression actually returns nil.

Comment: @kaushalmodi Yes. Though my emacs actually identifies itself as 25.0 now, so it might not be in 24.4.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that. @abo-abo Are you also on the emacs 25.0 development version? My `C-h` `v` `emacs-version` reads `24.4.8`.

Comment: @kaushalmodi Yes, the issue happens for current devel version.

Comment: @abo-abo Phew. We can then still rely on `emacs -Q` :) The version needs to then be updated in the question title.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## There are two ways

### Redefine `lisp--match-hidden-arg`:

```
(defun lisp--match-hidden-arg (limit) nil)
```

### Remove `lisp--match-hidden-arg` from `lisp-cl-font-lock-keywords-2` and `lisp-el-font-lock-keywords-2`

```
(setq lisp-el-font-lock-keywords-2
      (cl-delete 'lisp--match-hidden-arg lisp-el-font-lock-keywords-2
                 :key #'car))
```

## Please Do *NOT* Do That!

The coding style detected by `lisp--match-hidden-arg` is not very readable.

> "... a computer language is not just a way of getting a computer to
> perform operations, but rather ... it is a novel formal medium for
> expressing ideas about methodology"
>
> Abelson/Sussman "Structure and
> Interpretation of Computer Programs".

You write code so that people (and you yourself a year from today!) will read and *understand* it.
Coding conventions serve a purpose.
Please think before rejecting them.